# What is "The day before yesterday" in reported speech?

Tags: reported-speech, time-reference

If "yesterday" becomes "the previous day" in reported speech, what about "the day before yesterday"?

Direct Speech: "I came back **the day before yesterday**" he said.
Indirect/reported speech: He said that he came back __________.

Answer (score 1):

The relative time reference can be hard to render as reported speech, even for simple words like "yesterday".  The best solution is to rephrase them as absolute time references:

> (on Monday)  John says "I came back the day before yesterday".

> (reported)  John said that he came back on Saturday.

Remember, when reporting speech, your are describing the meaning of what was said, and not always using the same words.  Unless you had some reason to doubt him, you might just report the fact, and not the speech  "John came back on Saturday."

If necessary you can also use "on the previous day" or "two days previously" instead of "yesterday"  or "the day before yesterday".

> John said that he'd come back two days previously.

Back shifting to past perfect (had come) is possible in either case (but not mandatory)